# Add value from Dictionary to Array in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a Dictionary I want to add value in List or Array value. I created the below function:

```
public static void Main ()
{
    // string [] selected;
    List<string> selected = new List<string>();
    var data = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        {"A", "a"},
        {"B", "b"},
        {"C", "c"},
    };
    foreach (var result in data)
    {
        selected.Append(result.Value);
        // Console.WriteLine(result.Value);
        // selected.Add(result.Value);
        Console.WriteLine(selected);
    }
}
```

But this gets below output:

**System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String] System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]**

Please advice

Comment: Selected is a `List<string>` so that is the proper output. What output do you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
Console.WriteLine(selected);
```

do

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",",selected));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using `Linq`:

```
List<string> values = data.Select(item => item.Value).ToList();
```